# how to plot a 10*10 grid map and how to number the grid cells?(attached the model of grid)

Tags: navigation, motion-planning, programming-languages

regarding my assignment work i have to plot 10*10 grid with cells labelled in numbers.now only i have started to learn mat lab.i have tried lot of methods, to plot the grid. but none gave solution to me.guys please help me

Answer (score 2):

this is more a Matlab question.
for a 2D grid named G, you can plot it using *imagesc* fucntion.

Example:

```
colormap(gray);
imagesc(G, [-1 1]);
```

colormap here is used to plot the grid in grayscale color (-1 cells are displayed in black, 1 cells are displayed in white, and values between ]-1, 1[ are displayed in gray)